# How to use JMenuBar with JLayeredPane without setBounds?

Tags: jmenubar, jlayeredpane

There is a simple code: JMenuBar and the JPanel with the JBatton in the JLayeredPane. The problem is that the JLayeredPane overlaps the JMenuBar. How to fix it?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Simple extends JFrame{

    public Simple() {
        super("Simple");
        setSize(1000, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        JMenuBar menu =  new JMenuBar();
        JMenu File =  new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(File);
        setJMenuBar(menu);

        JPanel panel =  new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(1000, 500);
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        panel.add(button);
        getLayeredPane().add(panel,JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Simple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fined the resolution.

```
Container conn = getContentPane();
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

JLayeredPane desk =  new JDesktopPane();
desk.setOpaque(false);

conn.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
setJMenuBar(new MainMenu());
```